Unable to connect to Google Collab Pro. Unable to assign CPU runtime. Getting "Failed to assign a backend" Sorry, no backends avialable
I have been using Google Colab for free for a couple month and earlier today.  Opened up a new browser tab to look at another notebook and got the following error:  "Failed to assign a backend" Sorry, no backends availabe.
So I signed up Colab-Pro with 100 runtime units / month, rebooted PC and still gettting the same error message on just one Tab/Session.
I am only signed up for CPU, no GPU or accels. I need Numpy, Pandas, Seaborn and a bunch of other libraries I do not have local.  Is  there another way to get allocated runtime from somewhere?
